# What is the importance of Bézout's identity?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am creating a function which generates a privateKey for RSA. The underlying algorithm for generating a privateKey is the Extended Euclidean algorithm. According to Wikipedia, the output of this algorithm is a "Bézout's identity".

I never heard of Bézout's identity before and wanted to know what it's importance is and what is it used for, but I can't find a clear answer. Googling ["What is the importance of Bézout's identity?"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20the%20importance%20of%20B%C3%A9zout's%20identity) yields no relevant results. The closest thing I could find was a discussion on [Wikipedia:Talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AB%C3%A9zout's_identity)

> The point is that Bézout's identity is an important result which is
>   used in many areas of mathematics. In particular it is one of the
>   starting tools (with modular arithmetic) of Diophantine equation
>   theory

To someone who does not have an extensive mathematical background the above discussion is meaningless. Can someone describe the importance and use-cases for Bézout's identity in layman terms?

Comment: One purpose of Bézout's is to solve congruences related to the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

If $px+qy=1$ and $$z\equiv m\pmod p\\z\equiv n\pmod q$$

Then $$z\equiv npx+mqy\pmod{pq}$$

Comment: An important application of the Bezout's identity for the gcd is computing *modular inverses.* This works not only for integers but also for polynomials over a field. For example, a special case is computing inverses of quadratic numbers $\,\alpha = a+b\sqrt{d}\,$ by $ $ *rationalizing denominators,*  i.e $\ \dfrac{1}{\alpha} = \dfrac{\bar \alpha}{\alpha\bar\alpha}.\, $ The inversion  of complex numbers $\,\alpha = a+b\, i\,$ is a special case of such modular Bezout inversion. If this of interest then let me know and I can elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given integers $m,n$ (not both zero), [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) finds integers $x,y$ that satisfy: $$xm+ny=\gcd(m,n)$$

One important application is if we know $\gcd(m,n)=1$.  Then, we can take the above equation modulo $n$ to get $$xm\equiv 1\pmod{n}$$
This is useful, because we have found the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) to $m$, [modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

We have a constructive (and fast) way to find $x,y$, using the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

One reason a multiplicative inverse is useful is: suppose we want to find some integer $z$ satisfying the modular equation $$mz\equiv t\pmod{n}$$
Once we have found $x$, as above, we may multiply both sides by $x$ to get $$z\equiv 1z\equiv (xm)z\equiv xt\pmod{n}$$

Comment: I can see the relevance this has to cryptography, but where else is this kind of thing used?

Comment: [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is useful in many contexts; follow the link to see examples.

Answer (score 12):

Bezout's identity turns the qualitative statement "two numbers are relatively prime" into an equation which can be manipulated. For a proof or exercise about relatively prime numbers, one of the common first steps is to turn that condition into Bezout's identity.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have two $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$. Since they are in $\Bbb{Z}$, they have some greatest common divisor, which I'll call $d$. What Bezout's Identity states is that there exist $x, y \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that:
$$ax+by=d$$
The way we find $x, y$ is through the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. If you recall, the regular Euclidean Algorithm takes in $a, b$ and then gives us the greatest common divisor, but the Extended Eucliden Algorithm takes $a, b$ and then gives us the greatest common divisor $d$ along with $x, y$.

Now, to find [the RSA private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Key_generation), we need that $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod {\phi(n)}$ where $\gcd(e, \phi(n))=1$. Thus, by Bezout's Identity, we get there exist $x, y$ such that:
$$ex+\phi(n)y=1 \implies ex=1-\phi(n)y \implies ex \equiv 1 \pmod {\phi(n)}$$
Thus, $ex$ is the private key, so we can find the private key by figuring out $x$ using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

one very important consequence of bezout's theorem is that it tells you when the number $a$ has an inverse $\bmod m$.

This is of course when $(a,m)=1$.

The reason why the inverse exists is because  $sa+tm=1$ has solutions in $s$ and $t$.

This result is very important, as it tells us that the multative group $\bmod m$ has $\varphi(m)$ elements. Which is the reason why euler's theorem holds.

Answer (score 4):

Another important use of Bézout's identity is in the proof of [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Proof_using_B.C3.A9zout.27s_lemma):

> If a prime $p$ divides the product $ab$ of two integers $a$ and $b$,
>   $p$ must divide at least one of those integers $a$ and $b$.

Euclid's Lemma can be used to prove the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic):

> Every integer greater than 1 either is prime itself or is the product
>   of prime numbers, and that this product is unique, up to the order of
>   the factors.

As its name implies, the fundamental theorem of arithmetic is a cornerstone of number theory.