# Interesting or creative applications of Bezout’s (Bachet’s) Identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, big-list, applications

Bezout’s Identity (but discovered earlier, in a restricted form, by Bachet) is the following result.

> **Theorem:** Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers and let $d$ be their greatest common divisor. Then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $$ax+by=d.$$ In addition, the greatest common divisor $d$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written as $ax + by$, and every integer of the form $ax + by$ is a multiple of the greatest common divisor $d$.

Many theorems in elementary number theory are a result of this one (*e.g.,* Euclid's lemma, the Chinese remainder theorem).

I’m looking for interesting or creative applications of Bezout’s Identity to prove number theory results. One example is Catalan’s “complete integer solution” of the 2.2.3 equation $$X_1^2+X_2^2=Y_1^2+Y_2^2+Y_3^2, \tag{1}$$
which he gave as follows.

> Choose relatively prime integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and integers $u$ and $v$ such that $\beta u - \alpha v = 1$. Then all integer solutions of (1) are given, **without repetition**, by the formulas
>   \begin{align*}
>  x_1 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + y_3^2)u + \beta \theta,  &
>   y_1 &= x_1 + \alpha,  \\
>  x_2 &= \tfrac{1}{2}(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + y_3^2)v + \alpha \theta,  &
>   y_2 &= x_2 - \beta,
> \end{align*}
>   where $\theta$ is an arbitrary integer.

[cf. Dickson’s *History*, Vol II, p. 268; orig: Assoc franç., av. sc. 12, 1883, 98–101]

What other clever applications are there?

Comment: some here [link]: http://s3.amazonaws.com/aops-cdn.artofproblemsolving.com/resources/articles/olympiad-number-theory.pdf

Comment: The question is a bit broad, since any result using uniqueness of prime factorizations typically is based on Bezout, since Bezout $\Rightarrow$ atoms (irreducibles) are prime, which is the typical key step used in proving uniqueness of factorizations into atoms ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/164589/242) for a diagram of logical dependencies).  So you may as well as for application of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic or UFD property - which are ubiquitous.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Hmmm… I see what you mean. I guess I'm asking for examples of proofs that explicitly use the property, _i.e._ they say something like "since $x$ and $y$ are co-prime, there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $ax-by=1$" and go from there (like the Catalan example I gave).

Comment: @Kieren But you get that also by taking any proof that uses uniqueness and - instead of invoking the uniqueness theorem by name - substituting inline its Bezout-based proof (so then the proof "explicitly" uses Bezout).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Can you give me an example of such a proof, so I can try doing what you say here? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the importance of Bézout's identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074181/what-is-the-importance-of-b%c3%a9zouts-identity)

Comment: @Buraian: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I know the fundamentals of why it's important — what I want is concrete examples of its application.

Answer (score 2):

> **Lemma:** If $p$ is a prime number and $k$ is a positive integer not equal to $p$, then $\displaystyle p \mid \dbinom{p}{k}$.

**Proof:** For $k>p$, $\dbinom{p}{k} = 0$. Hence $p \mid \dbinom{p}{k}$.

For $0<k<p$, we have,

\begin{align*}
1&=ap+bk \ ; \ a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \\  
\implies\dbinom{p}{k} &= (ap+bk)\dbinom{p}{k}  \\  
&= ap\dbinom{p}{k} + bk\dbinom{p}{k} \\  
&= ap\dbinom{p}{k} + bp\dbinom{p-1}{k-1} \ \left(\because \dbinom{n}{r} = \dfrac{n}{r} \dbinom{n-1}{r-1}\right)  \\  
&= p\left(a\dbinom{p}{k} + b\dbinom{p-1}{k-1}\right) \\
\implies p&\mid \dbinom{p}{k} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \square
\end{align*}

This can be extended for composite $n$ with $\gcd (n,k) = d$ to show that $n \mid d \dbinom{n}{k}$.

Comment: Nice application!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s one: Dickson proved that all primitive integral solutions of the equation $$x^2-my^2=zw$$ are given by
\begin{align}
z &= el^2 + 2flq + gq^2, \\
w &= en^2 - 2fnr + gr^2, \\
x &= \pm (eln+fnq-flr-gqr), \\
y &= lr + nq,
\end{align}
where $f^2-eg=m$. Dickson says “Since $y=l$ and $w=g$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $f$ and $q$ such that $x=fl+gq$”, and then goes on to prove the theorem.

[@BillDubuque: If you stumble back on this post, I’d love for you to discuss it with respect to your comments under the main post. Thanks!]